# why should the state be changed only from mutation in vuex, vuejs app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to know, what would happen if I change the state from else where like say from component directly or from getter function ?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you could do that and probably all subscribers will be notified and nothing bad will happen, but the thing is that when you are using Vuex you agree to follow some design pattern proposed in there. Nothing would stop you from implementing your simple store (with only state and actions) that would share the state with vuejs and use it's reactivity. It would work- the thing is that Vuex is- as I said- a pattern that shows you the best way to track your changes and debug your app. In future your app's state may grow and I am assured that you would like to know what exactly is happening under the hood- thus you have mutations that have a simple task: update the state and help to track that exact change.

Using https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools you can easily see the transactions being done under the hood which would help others (or you in the future) what is going on with the state. Also, with mutations you are writing some kind of possibilities what in your state and how can be changed. Think of it as an API to access your data- no random or untrackable changes.